# How can I only call write function when value from series of IF statements change?

Tags: c#

I'm calculating the distance of the player from a point at any given time point in the game (using a series of IF statements), then returning the label associated with the nearest point. So that I can output that point to a text file.

Is there a way I can only get (or at least only output) the value if the value has changed?

I'm a fairly novice coder so please provide as much information as possible. Thanks in advance.

```
if (distPlayer5 < distPlayer2 && 
    distPlayer5 < distPlayer1 && 
    distPlayer5 < distPlayer4 && 
    distPlayer5 < distPlayer3 && 
    distPlayer5 < distPlayer6 && 
    distPlayer5 < distPlayer7)
{
    pathPoint = ("E");
    Debug.Log("pathpoint =" + pathPoint);
    WriteData();
}
if (distPlayer6 < distPlayer2 && 
    distPlayer6 < distPlayer1 && 
    distPlayer6 < distPlayer4 && 
    distPlayer6 < distPlayer3 && 
    distPlayer6 < distPlayer5 && 
    distPlayer6 < distPlayer7)
{
    pathPoint = ("F");
    Debug.Log("pathpoint =" + pathPoint);
    WriteData();
}
// ... etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value every frame but before that check if it changed:

```
if (distPlayer5 < distPlayer2 && distPlayer5 < distPlayer1 && distPlayer5 < distPlayer4 && distPlayer5 < distPlayer3 && distPlayer5 < distPlayer6 && distPlayer5 < distPlayer7)
{
    //...
}
//...

if(lastPathPoint != pathPoint){
    Debug.Log("pathpoint changed to: " + pathPoint);
}
lastPathPoint = pathPoint; //Store for the next frame
```

`lastPathPoint` should be declared where it will survive until next frame.

---

However you can create an array of `distPlayer` and then look for the index with the minimal value:

```
float minDistance = distPlayer[0];
int pathPoint = 0;
for (int a = 1; a < distPlayer.Length; a++)
{
    if (minDistance > distPlayer[a])
    {
        pathPoint = a;
        minDistance = distPlayer[a];
    }
}
if(lastPathPoint != pathPoint){
    Debug.Log("pathpoint changed to: " + pathPoint);
}
lastPathPoint = pathPoint; //Store for the next frame
```

Then you can use that index to get the related information regarding that player.

Comment: Will the array solution work if the distPlayer values are Vector3s? 
Also, I'm not really sure how an int can be a string like a?

Comment: Any value will work as long as you can compare them like that. In the second bit of code I changed the string to an int. That is a better practice because it is facter and reduces typo mistakes in many cases.

Comment: Did you mean "if(lastPathPoint != pathPoint)" ?

Comment: @PeteBloom indeed: fixed